# Latest version of Play app on Android 2.1

Tags: google-play-store, 2.1-eclair, google-apps

I've got a device (HTC Magic) with Android 2.1 (rooted, with CyanogenMod). It has Google Market app v2.23.6 - pretty old. I wonder, what's the latest version of Play that runs on Android 2.1?

In the past, this device once had trouble with updating the Market. I wonder if this is the same trouble all over again, or Market 2.23.6 is the latest I'm going to ever get?

EDIT: more about upgrading Market to Play [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=28073772).

The app still calls itself Market, not Play. This might be relevant; probably Market->Play transition changes the package ID or something.

Answer (score 1):

Have Froyo here running on Samsung Europa, latest version on this is, 4.1.6.

Perhaps you need to let the old Market run for a bit, then back out of it, it should auto-upgrade itself, *provided* you have a valid account and signed in.

Comment: That's Froyo, mine's Eclair, 2.1. Waiting for someone with 2.1...

Comment: Should not make a difference unless Google blocked updates to Market on the older eclair... give me a while and I'll reflash eclair and see what happens ..

Comment: I'm not so sure. I've reverted Market to the very original version (1.7 something), then forced an update; I've got 2.23.6 again. The linked XDA thread says you have to upgrade to Play via play.google.com somehow; I couldn't figure out how exactly.